# Не работают формы в openoffice и libre office

Tags: база-данных, windows, office, open-office

У нас в 11 классе задание создать базу данных, мы делаем ее в openoffice base, я знаю sql, как это примерно работает и т.д, но мне нужно доделать работу дома, а я не могу т.к. одно из заданий заключается в создании формы, я скачал и pen office, и libre office, и вроде все ок, но на вкладках создание отчетов и вкладке с формами  я вижу это:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
кнопка создать форму, если не понятно не кликабельна, а при открытии уже сделанной формы выходит ошибка, при чем я не могу даже сделать все с нуля т.к. при создании новой бд такая же проблема
P.S. на школьном пк все работает

Comment: А jre\jdk ты втыкал?

Comment: да, уже 10 раз по переобновлял и переустанавливал

Comment: 8-ю ветку? В линуксе зависимости рассказывают про 8.